# Reducing time taken to execute mysql query

Tags: mysql, insert, query-optimization

I have two databases with three similar tables(mdl_user, mdl_course and mdl_course_enrol).

The id values for users and courses in mdl_user and mdl_course are different in both the databases. Both values are referred by the third table, namely mdl_course_enrol. In database 1 the table is empty and in database 2 (nlbdb1_9), the table is filled. I am trying to execute a query such that the correct values get inputted in mdl_course_enrol. Following is my query:-

```
Insert into mdl_course_enrol 
(userid, courseid, registrationdate, expirydate, status, startdate, enddate, roleassignmentid)
Select u1.id, c1.id, t2.registrationdate, t2.expirydate, t2.status, t2.startdate, t2.enddate, t2.roleassignmentid
from 
nlbdb1_9.mdl_course_enrol as t2, mdl_user as u1, mdl_course as c1
where 
t2.userid=(Select u1.id from nlbdb1_9.mdl_user as u2 where t2.userid=u2.id and BINARY u2.email=BINARY u1.email)
and
t2.courseid=(Select c1.id from nlbdb1_9.mdl_course as c2 where t2.courseid=c2.id and BINARY c2.fullname = BINARY c1.fullname);
```

Following are the table structures:-

```
CREATE TABLE `mdl_course_enrol` (
  `id` bigint(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `userid` bigint(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `courseid` bigint(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `registrationdate` bigint(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `expirydate` bigint(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `status` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Not Attempted',
  `startdate` bigint(10) NOT NULL,
  `enddate` bigint(10) NOT NULL,
  `roleassignmentid` bigint(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=14962 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


CREATE TABLE `mdl_course` (
  `id` bigint(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `category` bigint(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `sortorder` bigint(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `fullname` varchar(254) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `shortname` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `idnumber` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `summary` longtext CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `summaryformat` tinyint(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `format` varchar(10) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'topics',
  `showgrades` tinyint(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `sectioncache` longtext CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `modinfo` longtext CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `newsitems` mediumint(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `startdate` bigint(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `numsections` mediumint(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `marker` bigint(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `maxbytes` bigint(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `legacyfiles` smallint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `showreports` smallint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `visible` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `visibleold` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `hiddensections` tinyint(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `groupmode` smallint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `groupmodeforce` smallint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `defaultgroupingid` bigint(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `lang` varchar(30) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `theme` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `timecreated` bigint(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `timemodified` bigint(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `requested` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `enablecompletion` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `completionstartonenrol` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `completionnotify` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `coursedisplay` tinyint(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `mdl_cour_cat_ix` (`category`),
  KEY `mdl_cour_idn_ix` (`idnumber`),
  KEY `mdl_cour_sho_ix` (`shortname`),
  KEY `mdl_cour_sor_ix` (`sortorder`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=45 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Central course table';

CREATE TABLE `mdl_user` (
  `id` bigint(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `auth` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'manual',
  `confirmed` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `policyagreed` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `deleted` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `mnethostid` bigint(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `username` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `password` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `pwdlastchange` bigint(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `idnumber` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `firstname` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `lastname` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `email` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `emailstop` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `nric` varchar(15) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `skype` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `yahoo` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `aim` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `msn` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `phone1` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `phone2` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `institution` varchar(40) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `department` varchar(30) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `address` varchar(70) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `city` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `country` varchar(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `lang` varchar(30) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'en_utf8',
  `theme` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `timezone` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '99',
  `firstaccess` bigint(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `lastaccess` bigint(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `lastlogin` bigint(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `currentlogin` bigint(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `lastip` varchar(15) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `secret` varchar(15) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `picture` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `url` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `description` text,
  `mailformat` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `maildigest` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `maildisplay` tinyint(2) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '2',
  `htmleditor` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `ajax` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `autosubscribe` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `trackforums` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `timemodified` bigint(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `trustbitmask` bigint(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `imagealt` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `screenreader` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `nlbid` bigint(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `mdl_user_mneuse_uix` (`mnethostid`,`username`),
  KEY `mdl_user_del_ix` (`deleted`),
  KEY `mdl_user_con_ix` (`confirmed`),
  KEY `mdl_user_fir_ix` (`firstname`),
  KEY `mdl_user_las_ix` (`lastname`),
  KEY `mdl_user_cit_ix` (`city`),
  KEY `mdl_user_cou_ix` (`country`),
  KEY `mdl_user_las2_ix` (`lastaccess`),
  KEY `mdl_user_ema_ix` (`email`),
  KEY `mdl_user_aut_ix` (`auth`),
  KEY `mdl_user_idn_ix` (`idnumber`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=5902 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='One record for each person';
```

I am trying to run the insert query but it is taking way too long. Is there any way to reduce the time?

Following is the output after explain select:-

[image]

Comment: Take the `SELECT ...` part of the query and run `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` on it. Post the output. At first glance, you have 1) [correlated subqueries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlated_subquery), which should be rewritten as JOINs; 2) WHERE clauses using BINARY - [they cannot be indexed without a special collation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4020812/mysql-binary-comparison-doesnt-use-index).

Comment: I have to use BINARY as both the databases are in a different collate format. I'll read up more on JOINs and see if it reduces some time.

Answer (score 0):

I can't promise that this will be faster.  However, I am guessing that the problem is in the correlated subqueries.  You can verify this by running the select-only part, to see if that runs in a reasonable time.

This version rewrites the correlated subqueries as joins:

```
Insert into mdl_course_enrol(userid, courseid, registrationdate, expirydate, status,
                             startdate, enddate, roleassignmentid)
    Select u.id, c.id, t2.registrationdate, t2.expirydate, t2.status, t2.startdate,
           t2.enddate, t2.roleassignmentid
    from nlbdb1_9.mdl_course_enrol t2 join
         nlbdb1_9.mdl_user u2
         on t2.userid = u2.userid join
         mdl_user u
         on (u.email collate utf8_unicode_ci = u2.email collate utf8_unicode_ci)  join
         nlbdb1_9.mdl_course c2
         on t2.courseid=c2.id join
         mdl_course c
         on (c2.fullname collate utf8_unicode_ci = c.fullname collate utf8_unicode_ci )
```

Comment: I just tried running this query with minor edits but not a lot of performance improvement. It is still running the query continuously for past half an hour.

Comment: Your best bet may be to create temporary tables for each off the lookup tables, separately.  These tables would have the old and new id in them.  Then build indexes and use these tables to lookup the values in the new table.

Comment: That was much faster. Thanks. Just finished inserting all the data.