# Indexing for BINARY LIKE operations in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database-indexes

I know that `varchar_pattern_ops` exists in Postgresql for fast, index-based searches in a `LIKE` query, but is there any similar functionality for MySQL?

I currently have a Django-MySQL setup where I have this query which runs on a non-indexed field and with a `BINARY LIKE` operation, and it takes over a minute to complete.

My query is a partial search from the beginning of the text - `text%`.

This is the table structure. The table actually contains over 20 fields, but I've included just the primary key and the field I'm searching on

```
+---------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+

| Field   | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra |

+-------------------------+---------------+------+-----+--

| id      | varchar(255)  | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |

| mid     | varchar(255)  | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
```

And this is the query -

```
select count(*) from table where mid binary like 'text%';
```

These are the indexes -

```
PRIMARY KEY index has cardinality 102820460
mid index has cardinality 756032
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2042269/how-to-speed-up-select-like-queries-in-mysql-on-multiple-columns

Comment: Thanks, although my question is a little bit more constrained than that. I've updated the question. My query is just a partial search from the beginning of the test.

Comment: In this case the index  should work .. because  the initil part can match witn the index .. try add  a simple index  on the column  but remember that for index  there is a limit of 767 bytes

Comment: The reason might be the cardinality of the values in this index, result in a bad selectivity. You can try `FORCE INDEX`. Also, find an explanation here: https://logicalread.com/mysql-index-cardinality-mc12/

Comment: Also, is the mentioned LIKE search the only condition? please post table structure (including indexes) and your full query.

Comment: If the search prefix is always _n_ characters or less (e.g. 4) then create a fixed width index on `mid` like so `CREATE INDEX ix_mid_4 ON mid(4)`

Comment: @Kaii - Added the required details

Comment: Next time please use `SHOW CREATE TABLE` so we can see which collations are used and how the indexes are defined. The reason seems to be a mismatch between attribute collation and the type of operation (binary compare). See https://stackoverflow.com/a/4020848/43959

Comment: `SHOW CREATE TABLE` gives this -
`CREATE TABLE table (id varchar(255) NOT NULL, mid varchar(255) NOT NULL) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8`

Comment: Also, when I do `SHOW TABLE STATUS`, I get `utf8_general_ci` as the collation for that table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the fact that   MySQL indexes the left side of a string.

Then a string column can use the index if the query use wildcard right side :

```
 SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE field LIKE "text%" # can use an index
```

but remember that for index there is a limit of 767 bytes

From Mysql DOC

> A B-tree index can be used for column comparisons in expressions that
>   use the =, >, >=, <, <=, or BETWEEN operators. The index also can be
>   used for LIKE comparisons if the argument to LIKE is a constant string
>   that does not start with a wildcard character.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/index-btree-hash.html

Comment: The column IS currently indexed, but it's not used for that query. I did an EXPLAIN for the query and while the `possible_keys` contained that index, the `key` column was `NULL`.

Comment: I found out that if i remove `binary` from the query and just execute `select count(*) from table where mid like 'text%';`, it uses the index and becomes insanely fast.

Comment: @Kaii - I understand. As far as I can tell, using `binary` returns a case-sensitive search. But the field contains only upper case values. So that's not a problem.