# Non-binary LIKE in MySQL through Django ORM

Tags: mysql, django, django-orm

This is a follow-up from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55685275/indexing-for-binary-like-operations-in-mysql). Although I can write a non-binary LIKE query such as - `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLE WHERE MID LIKE 'TEXT%'` in raw SQL, I would like to know if it's possible through the Django ORM.

Both `startswith` and `contains` seem to be using a binary pattern search.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try `istartswith` and `icontains`, which in MySQL resolve to `LIKE` rather than `LIKE BINARY`.

Note that with MySQL, the case-sensitivity of the comparison depends on the [collation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/databases/#collation-settings) set in the database (meaning that `i` lookups may still be case-sensitive!).

Comment: You're right. How could I have forgotten about that?

Comment: Thanks so much! Saved me tons of time!